# Extending the UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my .NET Core 2.0 MVC project I added additional values to extend the ApplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastLogin{ get; set; }

    }
```

In _LoginPartial I would like to get the Name, instead of the UserName which it gets by default

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using RioTintoQRManager.Models

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
     @UserManager.GetUserName(User)
}
```

How do I extend the UserManager, or create a new method that would be available in the view like UserManager.GetUserName is?

Comment: Why not call `UserManager.GetUserAsync()?.Name`? Would you prefer to only retrieve that value in order to be more 'efficient'?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your View shouldn't need to call back-end services on its own, you should provide it all the information it requires either through the `@Model` or through `ViewBag`/`ViewData`/`Session`.
However, if you need to get the current user you could just use:

```
var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
string userName = user.Name;
```

If you want to have your own `UserManager`, though, you'd have to do this:

```
public class MyManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {

    }

    public async Task<string> GetNameAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var user = await GetUserAsync(principal);
        return user.Name;
    }
}
```

And add it to the services:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<SomeContext>()
    .AddUserManager<MyManager>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Then you'd need to replace the references to `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` for `MyManager`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!! 
                            @{ var u = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User); }
                            @u.Name

Comment: I dont supose you have the code to SetNameAsync()??? I've tried ILSPY but I cant make head nor tail of it....

Comment: @Gray Well, `Name` is just a string property added to `ApplicationUser`, so normally you'd get the `ApplicationUser`, update the property and save the changes back to the db

Comment: How do you save changes back to the db? I’ve tried calling update but that does nothing. If you look at Email it has GetEmail() and SetEmail() methods.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Camilo-Terevinto I was able to figure out a solution. In my **_Layout.cshtml**

```
<span class="m-topbar__username rust-text">
   @{ var u = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(User); }
   @u.Name
 </span>
```